# text positioning in header section

Tags: html, css

is there any solution how to move text around in header section?
I have an `<h1>` tag whith email and I would like to move like 20% from left side of page and 50% form right side but all I can found is `text-align:right,left`, etc.

I add image so you can see on top of page there is this dark box whith email and view basket. How can I move that text the way I like?

[image: image show text on top of page from left 20% and from right around 40%]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you can position things like that...

**Positioning**

You are able to position elements using `absolute` and `relative` positioning, as seen in the example below, you can use `position: relative` for the parent container and `position: absolute` for the child and then use: `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left` and define how far away you want the child element to be from its parent. As seen in my example below.

http://jsfiddle.net/8aL05tey/4/

```css
header.header {
  position: relative;
}

header.header h1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <h1>
   email@email.com
  </h1>
</header>
```

**Flexbox**

You can also responsively position elements with `flexbox`. `Flexbox` can be relatively hard to understand if you've never messed around with it, there are plenty of SO questions with explanations in it. You can also read a bit about the properties [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

**Floats**

Alongside with `positioning`, you can `float` divs and other elements left and right using `float: left` and `float: right`. You can ready more about floats [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp). :)

> There are plenty of options for what you want to achieve and no real "right" answer, it's about exploring what works for you!

*Have a great day!*